# What use is a programming language if you're using a game engine and a 3D modeling software?

Tags: java, 3d, game-engine

I'm in the process of creating a game, and up until now, I have been working on a project in Java for about a month. I know a good deal of Java, and I've gotten everything in my game working up until the 3D modeling implementation of it.

I'm learning 3DS Max to create rough 3D models, and I don't really care if the models look good, as long as I create a working game. I read a lot on the Java 3D API on collision detection, AI, animation, scene graphs, and many other things. At first I was under the impression that I would create 3D models and import them into my Java program, and everything else would be handled with Java coding. I have just realized that I can use game engines for all of this and I can see that the whole process will be much simpler with their use, but I'm entirely unsure of my Java code's role in the whole design.

I believe that I can import models from 3DS Max into my game engine, but I don't know what comes next. What functionality does my Java code play in the game engine? The game engine supposedly creates all of the graphical elements to a game, but I thought a lot of that, such as animations, lighting, cameras, etc is done in the 3D modeling software? Also, where do I create the GUI for my game?

All of the Swing Components, at least as far as I can see, cannot compare to the graphics in a 3D modeling environment, and would be a stark, non-complex contrast to the 3D environment. I know this question would appear to be subjective, but I am still looking for a more objective answer that would hopefully detail the general differences in usage between the 3 core components (or other necessary ones) that I have listed above (Code, 3D Modeling, Game Engine).

Comment: If you're doing 3D stuff, then you probably don't want to be using Swing -- you probably want one of the libraries meant specifically for 3D work.

Comment: In regards to `What functionality does my Java code play in the game engine?`... The game engine itself is written in a programming language, so if its Java-based then it is very important. You would also need to do some Java programming to be able to interact with the game engine, and tell it what you want it to do.

Comment: @ WATTO Studios Aright, so I should still code in an IDE like Eclipse or should I use something specific to the game engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you still need a game engine to power your game, to take your models and textures and render them into an actual game with physics, collisions, and AI. Your modeling program does *not* do this for you. Now, if you decided to actually code the game engine yourself you would be in for alot of sleepless nights - it's a ***lot*** of work. But as you indicated, you are probably going to use one of the available game engines in order to cut down on the amount of coding you need to do.

You're question is valid, in that you can select a game engine written in any one of a number of languages, so why Java? Nobody can really answer that but you - but one of the strong points about Java is portability. If you want to create a game that you can run on a variety of platforms then Java is not a bad choice at all. Another strong point is the sheer amount of available code that can be reused, normally at low (or no cost).

It really comes down to what your final vision of your product is, and your target audience.

Comment: I see, that helped a lot, thanks. One last question I have is how I connect my code to my game engine? I have a lot of written code in an eclipse project, but I don't understand how I import my code into the already-created engine, or vice versa. If this is specific to the game engine, I can look into it specifically, but if there is  a general answer, that would be great. Thank you for your time.